# Orchard Static file with Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, orchardcms

So we all know how to serve all static files in a folder:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
  <!--
  iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
  accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
  -->
  <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
```

Now it get's interesting if you try to use Orchard authorization to serve files only to a specific role. I tried standard MVC aproches but they did not work since you will need to modify Orchard.Web `web.config` and I don't want to do that.

Imagine I can only modify my own module's `web.config` to achieve this. Is there any way to do it? I tried playing with that snippet bu not luck since I don't understand it very well.

Orchard is not very well documented so any link to specific parts of the documentation which elaborate on this issue is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by adding a specific [route](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module#AddingtheRoute) that redirects to an action of a MVC controller. This action checks the permissions (e.g. based on Orchard role) and streams the file, otherwise redirects to 404 or 500.

Comment: That is similar to what I've done. I created a controller action which takes a string path, checks permission and returns file if it exists. I would still like to know if there is any way to do it with `web.config`

Comment: The web.config in modules is not active, so no. At least not the web.config that is at the root of the module. It /might/ be possible with the a web.config in the folder from which the files are being served.

Comment: That's actually what I meant. The `web.config` in the folder in which files are being saved. You put the staticfile snippet there as well. Is there a way to use Orchard Authorization just in there?